# Wrong string concatenation using Bash Windows Subsystem

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, string, concatenation

I'm having headaches to know why my script doesn't work as expected under windows subsystem linux.

My version from the store : `Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)` (I tried ubuntu too, with the same results)

And my bash version : `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

This is my basic script only to show the issue :

```
PROJECT_ENV="development"
echo $PROJECT_ENV
compose_file="docker-compose.${PROJECT_ENV}.build.yml"
echo $compose_file
```

And it outputs :

```
.build.ymlpose.development
```

As i understand, that output doesn't make any sense to me, I tried to reinstall bash but i'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a carriage return character at the end of `PROJECT_ENV` variable content. This is probably because your script uses `CR+LF` [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) (proper in DOS/Windows) instead of sole `LF` (Unix/Linux).

In Linux `dos2unix` is the right tool to fix it.

The detailed explanation is as follows:

1. The final `echo` prints

   ```
   docker-compose.development
   ```
2. `CR` makes the terminal go back to the beginning of the line.
3. The consecutive characters overwrite the previous text:

   ```
   .build.yml
   ```
4. Therefore the result is:

   ```
   .build.ymlpose.development
   ```